# bind multi JqGrid inside the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jqgrid

i have to bind jqGrids inside an accordion (JQ UI) and here is my code :

here i draw the grid inside the accordion .

```
<div id="accordion" class="accordion-style2">
    <div class="group">
@foreach (var mytable in lstmytable )
{
        <h3 class="accordion-header">mytable.DAY_NAME</h3>
    <div divgrid="true" id="myDiv_@mytable.DAY_ID">
        <p>
            <table grid="true" id="grid_table_@mytable.DAY_ID"></table>
            <div pagerid="true" id="grid-pager_@mytable.DAY_ID"></div>
        </p>
    </div>
}
    </div>
    </div>
//here i get the ids from the grid and the pager 
 $("[divgrid='true']").each(function () {
               var GridID = jQuery(this).find("table").attr("id");
               var PagerID = jQuery(this).find("div").attr("id");
               BindGrid(GridID, PagerID);
            });

//here i bind the grids using different id each time .
BindGrid(gridID,PagerID)
{
var grid_selector = GridID;
var pager_selector = PagerID;
//my grid implementation 
}
```

but it never bind any grid

Comment: You removed all really relavant code from your question and replaced it with "//my grid implementation".

Answer (score 0):

i find out that the grid_selector need to be have a # before it to become like this

```
    var grid_selector = "#" + GridID;
    var pager_selector = "#" + PagerID;
```